# what is the function of clear custom split data

Tags: edges, normals, geometry

I was making a model and then when I wanted to add *Auto Smooth* this weird thing appeared.
[image: screenshot 1]

Searching online I could fix it by going to *Geometry Data* and pressing
*Clear Custom Split Normals Data*.
[image: screenshot 2]
I searched online for an explanation for this problem and why *Clear Custom Split Normals Data* fix this but I could not get any answer.

Can someone explain to me why this happens and what is the function of *Clear Custom Split Normals Data*?

This may be a silly question but I hope someone can help me.
Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

There are *Face Normals*, *Split Normals*, and *Vertex Normals*. Like the *Face Normals*, the *Split Normals* affect the shading of an object. They are important for hard-surface modeling, and can solve but also introduce problems.

*Split Normals Data* can exist on imported objects or can be created by the two modifiers: *Normal Edit* and *Weighted Normal* when the modifiers are applied. To get rid of this data you need to press the *Clear Custom Split Normals Data* button. The button removes the data layer.

There is an overlay that makes the normals visible in *Edit* mode:

[image: normals overlay]

Here are three examples of shading.

1. No custom split normals:
   [image: example 1]
2. Weighted normals by the modifier:
   [image: example 2]
3. Copied split normals from a sphere by the *Normal Edit* modifier:
   [image: example 3]

Answer (score 0):

Usually normals simply point to the direction perpendicular to the face. It tells how light should behave when hitting that surface. Smooth shading works by creating a smooth gradient between the normals. More info [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PMgjVJogIbc).

Custom normals allow you to bend the rules, e.g. stylized look like shown [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hwhM437Xvks).

It is unclear to me how you got custom normals on your model, but they are typically calculated *in the shadows* under the hood (bad pun), so who knows what magic occurred there.