# Adding Custom normals to an object?

Tags: normals

How do you put custom normals on a mesh? Im trying to create a seamless cell fracture and Ive been told you can do it with a data transfer modifier, but the original mesh has to have custom normals? Someone please ELI5.

Comment: For more context here is the related question you've asked [Shading issues with custom normals on cell fractured object](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/241140/107598)

Comment: You can edit the normals with the menu *Mesh > Normals (Alt+N)* in *Edit* mode or add and apply an *Edit Normals* or *Weighted Normals* modifier. Look [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/239473/107598) for the overlay settings to make the normals visible.